# HDD failed now after replacement no Network functions when booted

Tags: networking

As title says one of the hdds failed had DC replace said HDD and when they boot there is no ping so no server is in rescue mode. Any clue as to how I can get it to work again?

Comment: how was the system configured when the hard drive died?  If your system was RAID0 then you have no choice but to reinstall because there's no recovery from that type of failure.

Comment: system was in RAID1 I have access to file system and was able to add the new hdd back. Only issue I'm having is when I boot from hdd I lose all network access to the server.

To add above I meant to write now the server is in rescue mode so I have access to my file system through rescue mode